# How to highlight tree node on click of button in element-ui

Tags: element-ui

I am having el-tree> element and 1 button showNode.
so on click of this button i want to highlight a node with given index.
How to call **highlight-current** on click of button?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tree):

> *highlight-current*: whether current node is highlighted

`highlight-current` is just a read-only attribute, in order to highlight a specific node, you have to call the method `setCurrentKey`

> *setCurrentKey*: set highlighted node by key, only works when node-key is assigned, the param (key) is the node's key to be highlighted

So, you need first to add a key to every node, using the property key:

> *node-key*: unique identity key name for nodes, its value should be unique across the whole tree

Like following example:

```
<el-tree
  :data="myData"
  node-key="id">
</el-tree>
```

And then, call the method `setCurrentKey` on the `click` event attached to your button:

```
<el-button @click="setCurrentKey(myData[index].id)">Highlight the n-index node</el-button>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

**Updated:** The code above works only on 2.x version, here an example to highlite a node on version 1.4.13 (but I can't expand a node, so I had to expand all the tree):

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        data: [{
          label: 'Level one 1',
          id: 1,
          children: [{
            label: 'Level two 1-1',
            id: 11
          }]
        }, {
          label: 'Level one 2',
          id: 2,
          children: [{
            label: 'Level two 2-1',
            id: 21,
            children: [{
              label: 'Level three 2-1-1',
              id: 211
            }]
          }, {
            label: 'Level two 2-2',
            id: 22,
            children: [{
              label: 'Level three 2-2-1',
              id: 221
            }]
          }]
        }],
        defaultProps: {
          children: 'children',
          label: 'label'
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleNodeClick(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      renderContent(h, { node, data, store }) {
        let btn = h('span', {
          props: {type: 'success'},
          domProps: {
            innerHTML: data.label,
            id: "node-id-" + data.id
          }
        })
        return btn
      },
      handleBtnClick(){
        //Highlite the 211
       document.getElementById("node-id-211").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.13/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@1.4.13/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-tree :data="data" :props="defaultProps" @node-click="handleNodeClick" :render-content="renderContent" :default-expand-all="true"></el-tree>
<el-button @click="handleBtnClick">Highlight the 211 node</el-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion. but all above components are present in version 2.o and above. but i am using previous version so can you suggest me solution in previous version?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid with version 1.4.13 you cannot highlight a node by key. You could try with css/javascript something like: `document.getElementsByClassName("el-tree-node")[index].classList.add("selected")` and define a `background-color` for class `selected`.

Comment: @POM I've updated my answer with a trick to highlite a node on previous version. Bye.